# trying to display a list of customers and their balance on a page with flutterflow

Tags: flutterflow

With FlutterFlow, I'm trying to display a list of customers and their balance on a page. The problem is that I don't know how to do it, because to obtain the list of clients I do it with the "backend query" function. But if I want to "set from a variable" I can't find an option to do what I need, because it only shows me the customer attributes.

I have two schemas, clients and clothes. I want to visualize the list of clients and next to them the balance, which would be the sum of all the clothes they sold. My structure is like this:
clients:
-name(string)
-clothes ( List <Doc Reference (clothes)>

clothes:
-name(string)
-amount (integer)
-paid (boolean)

I want to know if I can do this in a simple way or if I need to write a function and how I can do it.